# jQuery i cant assign variable to element's val attribute dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax

I add list element to `#exercise-checkbox-list` with ajax, this code works for backend side, when user add exercise for the first time everything is okay but for the second time new exercise's id becomes the first added element's this tag's (<a href='#' val="user_exercise_id" class="fa fa-times">) val because jQuery('#exercise-times-button').attr('val', user_exercise_id) this code set val by looking at element id and all exercises has same id so it change first element's tag's val.How to solve this problem ?

```
     jQuery.ajax({
                  url: '/ajax/add_exercise/',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: {
                     'exercise_type': 0,
                     'exercise_id': exercise_id,
                     'duration': duration,
                     'daily_person_id': daily_person_id,
                     'daily_exercise_program_id': daily_exercise_program_id,
                     'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                    },
                     type: 'POST',
                     success: function (data) {
                       user_exercise_id = data.user_exercise_id;
                       console.log(user_exercise_id);              
                       jQuery("#exercise-checkbox-list").append('<li> <label> <span><strong>' + exercise_name + "| " + duration + " min" + " | " + how_many_calorie_burn + " cal burned" + '<strong></span>\n <a href=\'#\'\n' +
                                        '                                                               class="fa fa-pencil"></a>\n' +
                                        '                                                            <a href=\'#\' val="user_exercise_id" class="fa fa-times"></a> </label> </li>');
                      jQuery('#exercise-times-button').attr('val', user_exercise_id);
                      }
            });
```

Comment: Please review [mcve] with the emphasis on minimal - it looks like 90% of the code provided has no relevance to the question.

Comment: It *looks like* the only relevant code is `.append('<a href=\'#\' val="user_exercise_id" class="fa fa-times">')` - you're already using `' + variable + '` so do the same: `.append('<a href=\'#\' val="' + user_exercise_id + '" class="fa fa-times">')`  (note where it's `'` and where it's `"` which can be hard to see when next to each other)

Comment: thanks, I will be more careful about that for next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add Id in tag a like this

```
<a href="#" id="myTag"></a>
```

and after that add attr like this:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
              url: '/ajax/add_exercise/',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: {
                 'exercise_type': 0,
                 'exercise_id': exercise_id,
                 'duration': duration,
                 'daily_person_id': daily_person_id,
                 'daily_exercise_program_id': daily_exercise_program_id,
                 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
                },
                 type: 'POST',
                 success: function (data) {
                   $('#myTag').attr('val', data.user_exercise_id);
                   }
            }
```

Comment: when user add list element for the second time its user_exercise_id become the first element's val because list elements has same id. How can i solve this ?